# How To Increment Numbers in Calculated field of TQuery?

Tags: delphi, foxpro, bde, quickreports, tquery

I Have `TQuery` With Calculated Field `N`.
How To Increment Numbers in the example (`N` starts with 5):

[image]

I tried this but Nothing:

```
procedure TForm1.Query1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
var i:integer;
begin
  i := strtoint(edit2.Text);
  Query1['N'] := inttostr(i+1);
end;
```

result:

```
N
2
2
2
2
.
.
```

Note: Foxpro database ,i use BDE to connect with ,It does not have to be a calculated field ,i want the Incremented value to use it in print of quickreport like a single reference for each Page (not pagenumber).

Comment: Nothing? Nothing at all? No error, no value, nothing? If so, can you verify if this code is called at all? If you did get something, but not what you expected, could you pretty please explain what you got?

Comment: Calculated field? Calculated how?

Comment: When you say "Nothing",I suspect your `N` values are the same for all records? BTW, which database? which provider? does it have to be a calculated field?

Comment: the code i try it work but not what expected

Comment: yes the same value for all records

Comment: foxpro database ,i use BDE to connect with ,It does not have to be a calculated field ,i want the Incremented value to use it in print of quickreport

Comment: You might want to try `Query1.RecNo` for the calculated field value.

Comment: Thank you @kobik `Query1.RecNo+strtoint(edit2.Text)-1` this work and no needed to calculated field

Comment: @Asad, You are welcome. You can post your own answer to finalize the q.

Answer (score 1):

I Found This Solution With The Help Of *@kobik*

In Printing Of **TQRLabel** I Add This Code And No Needed To The **Calculated Field** Or Other Varible:

```
procedure TForm1.QRLabel1Print(sender: TObject; var Value: string);
begin
value:=inttostr(Query1.RecNo+strtoint(edit2.Text)-1);
end;
```

- The Tedit To Costume The Start Number At Runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way that I test it:

1- declare a global variable for saving auto number

2- Set it in `FormShow` to 5

3- In `OnCalcFields` assign global variable to the new field

4- increment global variable

Notes: Do not use TEdit or any thing for show the result of calculate field, because it will  just show the first result. but all the result will save in table or query correctly.

Codes

Global Variable:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  i : Integer;
```

Form Show:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
    i := 5;
end;
```

Calc Filed:

```
procedure TForm1.adoqry1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
   adoqry1['n'] := i;
   //OR adoqry1N.AsInteger := i;
   //OR adoqry1.FieldByName('n').AsInteger := i;

   i := i + 1;
end;
```

At the end, I test it with `ADOQuery`.

Comment: This won't work when scrolling the dataset. I posted a similar answer but deleted it after I tested it.

Comment: it work for me,But this method is not concise ,Simply put this code when CalcFields : `Query1.RecNo+strtoint(edit2.Text)-1` ,the tedit to costume the start number

Comment: and for more concise in printing TQRLabel i add this code and no needed to the calculated field : `procedure TForm1.QRLabel1Print(sender: TObject; var Value: string);
begin
value:=inttostr(Query1.RecNo+strtoint(edit2.Text)-1);
end;` ,,the tedit to costume the start number in runtime.

Comment: I think it is better you explain your question more.